# PHP: Devided by Zero error

Tags: php

This error shows up:

> Warning: Division by zero in /home/evoheau/public_html/store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php on line 157Warning: Division by zero in /home/evoheau/public_html/store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php on line 158
>   Warning: Division by zero in /home/evoheau/public_html/store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php on line 167

PHP Code (store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php):

Line 157:

```
    $this->data['Sale_Click']   =  $this->currency->format($this->data['UrlCount'] * $this->affiliate->getPayClickCount() / $this->affiliate->getClickCount());
    $Sale_Click   =  $this->data['UrlCount'] * $this->affiliate->getPayClickCount() / $this->affiliate->getClickCount();
```

Line 158:

```
$this->data['Sale_Commission']     =  $this->data['UrlCount'] * $this->affiliate->getPayClickCount() / $this->affiliate->getClickCount();
```

Edited Code:

```
<?php
class ControllerAffiliateSales extends Controller {
    private $error = array();

    public function index() {
        if (!$this->affiliate->isLogged()) {
            $this->redirect(HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=affiliate/account');
        }

        $this->document->breadcrumbs = array();

        $this->document->breadcrumbs[] = array(
            'href'      => HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=common/home',
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'separator' => FALSE
        );

        $this->document->breadcrumbs[] = array(
            'href'      => HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=affiliate/account',
            'text'      => $this->language->get('Account'),
            'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
        );

        $this->document->breadcrumbs[] = array(
            'href'      => HTTP_SERVER . 'index.php?route=affiliate/sales',
            'text'      => $this->language->get('Sales'),
            'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
        );


    $this->language->load('affiliate/sales');

    $this->data['text_Account_Details'] = $this->language->get('text_Account_Details');
    $this->data['text_Pay_Inprogress'] = $this->language->get('text_Pay_Inprogress');
    $this->data['text_Payment_History'] = $this->language->get('text_Payment_History');
    $this->data['text_Customer_Details'] = $this->language->get('text_Customer_Details');
    $this->data['text_InActive'] = $this->language->get('text_InActive');
    $this->data['text_Active'] = $this->language->get('text_Active');
    $this->data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

    $this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('affiliate/account');

    $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
    $this->data['text_my_account'] = $this->language->get('text_my_account');
    $this->data['text_my_orders'] = $this->language->get('text_my_orders');


    $this->load->model('affiliate/afforder');

    $this->data['affiliate_id']=$this->affiliate->isLogged();

    $refamounts = $this->model_affiliate_afforder->getrefamount();
    $this->data['myrefamounts'] = array();
    foreach ($refamounts as $refamount)
    {
          $this->data['myrefamounts'] = array(
                    'key'     => $refamount['key'],
                    'value'   => $refamount['value']
          );
  }
    $refbonus = $this->model_affiliate_afforder->getrefbonus();
    $this->data['refbonusamt'] = array();
    foreach ($refbonus as $refbonus1)
    {
          $this->data['refbonusamt'] = array(
                    'key'     => $refbonus1['key'],
                    'value'   => $refbonus1['value']
          );
  }
    $refpercents = $this->model_affiliate_afforder->getrefpercent();
    $this->data['refpercentage'] = array();
    foreach ($refpercents as $refpercent)
    {
          $this->data['refpercentage'] = array(
                    'key'     => $refpercent['key'],
                    'value'   => $refpercent['value']
          );
  }

    $MyTotalReferrals = $this->model_affiliate_afforder->getTotalReferrals($this->data['affiliate_id']);
    $this->data['TotalRef'][] = array();
    foreach ($MyTotalReferrals as $TotalReferrals)
    {
          $this->data['TotalRef'] = array(
                      'Total' => $TotalReferrals['tot']
          );
  }

    $GuestReferrals = $this->model_affiliate_afforder->getTotalGuestReferrals($this->data['affiliate_id']);
    $this->data['GuestCount'][] = array();
    foreach ($GuestReferrals as $GuestReferral)
    {
          $this->data['GuestCount'] = array(
                      'Total' => $GuestReferral['tot']
          );
  }
    $this->data['config_refcustomer'] = $this->config->get('config_refcustomer');

    // if ($this->affiliate->affiliate_grp() != 1 )exit;
    $referral_info = $this->model_affiliate_afforder->getReferralsDetails($this->data['affiliate_id']);
  $this->data['referrals'] = array();
    foreach ($referral_info as $refers)
    {

        $this->data['referrals'][] = array(
                  'referral_id' => $refers['referral_id'],
                'affiliate_id' => $refers['affiliate_id'],
                'customer_id' => $refers['customer_id'],
                'firstname' => $refers['firstname'],
                'lastname' => $refers['lastname'],
                'status' => $refers['status'],
                'referred_date' => $refers['referred_date'],
            );
    }


    $referralorder_info = $this->model_affiliate_afforder->getReferralOrderDetails($this->data['affiliate_id']);
  $this->data['referralorders'] = array();
    foreach ($referralorder_info as $refers)
    {

        $this->data['referralorders'][] = array(
                  'referral_id' => $refers['referral_id'],
                'affiliate_id' => $refers['affiliate_id'],
                'customer_id' => $refers['customer_id'],
                'firstname' => $refers['firstname'],
                'lastname' => $refers['lastname'],
                'referred_date' => $refers['referred_date'],
                'total' => $refers['total'],
                'ordered_date' => $refers['date_added'],
                'Earnings' => $refers['Earnings'],
                'Payment_Status' => $refers['Payment_Status'],
                'Payment_date' => $refers['Payment_date']
                );
    }

      $this->data['flag_payclickcount_enable']=$this->affiliate->getPayClickEnable();
      $this->data['flag_paypercust_enable']=$this->affiliate->getPayPerCustEnable();
      if (isset($this->request->post['config_payperaffiliate_enable'])) {
            $this->data['payperaffiliate_enable'] = $this->request->post['config_payperaffiliate_enable'];
        } else {
            $this->data['payperaffiliate_enable'] = $this->config->get('config_payperaffiliate_enable');
        }



        $this->load->model('affiliate/transaction');


      $this->data['flag_paypersale_enable']=$this->affiliate->getPayPerSaleEnable();
      $this->data['flag_flatratesale_enable']=$this->affiliate->getFlatRateSaleEnable();

      $AffAccInfo = $this->model_affiliate_afforder->getAffAcctDetails($this->data['affiliate_id']);
      $this->data['AffAccDetails']= array();

            $this->data['UrlCount']     =  $this->model_affiliate_afforder->getURLCount($this->data['affiliate_id']);


            $this->data['Sale_Click']   =  $this->currency->format($this->data['UrlCount'] * $this->affiliate->getPayClickCount() / $this->affiliate->getClickCount());
            $Sale_Click   =  $this->data['UrlCount'] * $this->affiliate->getPayClickCount() / $this->affiliate->getClickCount();


            $this->data['Total_Customers']     =  $this->model_affiliate_afforder->getTotalReferralsCount($this->data['affiliate_id']);
            $this->data['Total_Guests']        =  $this->model_affiliate_afforder->getTotalGuestCount($this->data['affiliate_id']);
            $Sale_CustomerCount  =  $this->data['Total_Customers'] * $this->affiliate->getPayperCust();
            $this->data['Sale_CustomerCount']  =  $this->currency->format($this->data['Total_Customers'] * $this->affiliate->getPayperCust() );

            $Sale_Order        =  $this->model_affiliate_afforder->getTotalSaleOrder($this->data['affiliate_id']);
            $this->data['Sale_Order']          =  $this->currency->format($this->model_affiliate_afforder->getTotalSaleOrder($this->data['affiliate_id']));

            if ($this->affiliate->getClickCount()!=0){
                $this->data['Sale_Commission']     =  $this->data['UrlCount'] * $this->affiliate->getPayClickCount() / $this->affiliate->getClickCount();

            }

            $this->data['afftransaction'] = $this->model_affiliate_transaction->getAffRegistration();
            $afftransaction  =  $this->data['afftransaction'];

            $Sale_Total   =  $Sale_Click + $Sale_CustomerCount + $Sale_Order + $afftransaction ;
            $this->data['Sale_Total']   =  $this->currency->format($Sale_Click + $Sale_CustomerCount + $Sale_Order + $afftransaction ) ;




        if($afftransaction){
            $this->data['payperaffiliate_enable']=1;
        }
        //$balance   =  $this->model_affiliate_transaction->getBalance(); 
        //$balance   =  $Sale_Click + $Sale_CustomerCount  + $Sale_Order + $Sale_Total + $afftransaction;
        $balance     =  $Sale_Click + $Sale_CustomerCount  + $Sale_Order + $afftransaction;

        $this->data['balance'] = $this->currency->format($balance);

        $combalances     =  $this->model_affiliate_transaction->myadminadjustments(); 
        $this->data['combalances'] = $this->currency->format($combalances);

        $totalbalance   =  $balance + $combalances ;
        $this->data['totalbalance']   =  $this->currency->format($balance + $combalances) ;         


        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        $this->id       = 'content';

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/affiliate/sales.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/affiliate/sales.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/affiliate/sales.tpl';
        }

        $this->children = array(
            'common/header',
            'common/footer',
            'common/column_left',
            'common/column_right'
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render(TRUE), $this->config->get('config_compression'));


    }



    private function validate() {
        if (!$this->customer->login($this->request->post['email'], $this->request->post['password'])) {
            $this->error['message'] = $this->language->get('error_login');
        }

        if (!$this->error) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

New Error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: Sale_Click in /home/evoheau/public_html/store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php on line 179
>   Notice: Undefined variable: Sale_Click in /home/evoheau/public_html/store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php on line 180
>   Notice: Undefined variable: Sale_Click in /home/evoheau/public_html/store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php on line 190

Newest Error:

> Warning: Division by zero in /home/evoheau/public_html/store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php on line 159
>   Warning: Division by zero in /home/evoheau/public_html/store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php on line 160

Comment: make sure `$this->affiliate->getClickCount()` 's value is not null ,undefined or not set.

Comment: Check using condition and then divide like `if(isset(whatever) && whatever > 0) { divide }`

Comment: if there's a division by zero, just look for the division, in this case: / $this->affiliate->getClickCount(); That means that $this->affiliate->getClickCount() is 0 or null or something similar at some point, add an exception or something there

Comment: Looks like $this->affiliate->getClickCount() is the problem you are getting zero as returned value.

Comment: if (something > 0)?
$this->data['Sale_Commission']     =  $this->data['UrlCount'] * $this->affiliate->getPayClickCount() / $this->affiliate->getClickCount();
break;

Comment: Please. SO is not a debugging service. Narrow down your problem and try identify the cause.

Comment: It is a simple error? No one able to provide code snippet?

Answer (score 3):

The value of  `$this->affiliate->getClickCount()`  might be `0`. Make sure that it is a non-zero value

check,

```
if ($this->affiliate->getClickCount()!=0)
{
 // code
}
```

Comment: How do I do that wiith a If statement?

Comment: I now have these errors: 
Notice: Undefined variable: Sale_Click in /home/evoheau/public_html/store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php on line 179Notice: Undefined variable: Sale_Click in /home/evoheau/public_html/store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php on line 180Notice: Undefined variable: Sale_Click in /home/evoheau/public_html/store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php on line 190

Comment: Edit your question and post your full code

Comment: I have posted full code above.

Comment: How do I define variable? Where?

Comment: what is in line 179 and 190?

Comment: 179 - $Sale_Total   =  $Sale_Click + $Sale_CustomerCount + $Sale_Order + $afftransaction ;
   $this->data['Sale_Total']   =  $this->currency->format($Sale_Click + $Sale_CustomerCount + $Sale_Order + $afftransaction ) ;

190 - $balance  = $Sale_Click + $Sale_CustomerCount  + $Sale_Order + $afftransaction;

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index. try replace the variable value with 0

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this

```
if ($this->affiliate->getClickCount()>0) {
    $this->data['Sale_Commission']     =  $this->data['UrlCount'] * $this->affiliate->getPayClickCount() / $this->affiliate->getClickCount();
}
```

Comment: This caused - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/evoheau/public_html/store/catalog/controller/affiliate/sales.php on line 168

Comment: ling.s worked this didn't.

Comment: @Josh just update your question with edited code so that I can have a look to correct it. Thanks.